# WPF: Meaning of the first two "same" arguments in RoutedUICommand()

Tags: c#, wpf

In all examples that I checked, first two arguments of `RoutedUICommand()` are same string, e.g.

```
private static RoutedUICommand add = new RoutedUICommand("Add", "Add", typeof(CommandLibrary));
```

What the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check the metadata for the meaning by pressing F12 with your I-beam on the class while using Visual Studio.
Anyway, with the constructor `RoutedUICommand(String, String, Type)`: the *first* string is a descriptive text, the *second* is the name, and the third is the owner type. It doesn't have to be the same.
Consider this example [here](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/routeduicommand/):

```
public static RoutedCommand GreetUserCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Howdy! Just to say hello, nothing else.", "GreetUser", typeof(MainWindow));
```

and usage of the view:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static loc:MainWindow.GreetUserCommand}" 
                    CanExecute="GreetUser_CanExecute" Executed="GreetUser_Executed"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Command="{x:Static loc:MainWindow.GreetUserCommand}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
```